# json_encode escaping character '<'

Tags: php, json

i tried to encode character '<' with json_encode() function but the output is always unclosed or unfinished json string.

this is my code:

```
echo json_encode('<');
```

the output:

```
"
```

i already even tried to use this code:

```
echo json_encode(array_map('utf8_encode',['<']));
```

but the output still

```
{["
```

but if i tried to encode '<>'

```
echo json_encode('<>');
```

the output is just like what i wanted:

```
"<>"
```

Please help me Thanks

Comment: It works fine for me https://3v4l.org/vtfJW

Comment: my php version is 7.1.18, is that influence it?, i tried it in my sever,
in localhost or localserver it works fine too

Comment: Not sure - as you can see from the demo it runs the code on every version of PHP from 5,6,38 to 7.3.0, including 7.1.18. Perhaps there's an issue with how you're displaying the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fault is not the json_encode or php version.
it was the header `Content-Encoding` , i don't why but the header Content-Encoding is set to `gzip`.

so the solution i have  is to change the header Content-Encoding by adding following code in my .php:

```
header('Content-Encoding: none');
```

i found this by inspecting header output in Postman

Thanks for your reply all

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type